# How to get access to slotted component / template in vue-test-utils?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils

Component:

```
<template>
  <MyComponent>
    <div class="in-slot">Hello world</div>
  </MyComponent>
</template>
```

How to get access to div.in-slot and test his text?

Answer (score 1):

If we suppose that you imported the parent component as MyParentComponent in your test file, this should work:

```
const wrapper = mount(MyParentComponent, {options})
expect(wrapper.find('.in-slot').text()).toBe('Hello world')
```